# Loading local FASTA file in igv.js

Tags: visualization, igv

I'm trying to use igv.js for a very simple visualization of some genomic alignments, but I can't get past the first step.  I have a FASTA file that I want to use as the reference, but igv.js consistently gives an error when I try to load that file.  The file is a valid FASTA (have tested others from other sources to be sure - same error), and I can specify a remote https:// file, but not a local file.

Here's the HTML page I'm working on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Local FASTA Test</title>

    <!-- IGV JS-->
    <script src="https://igv.org/web/release/2.1.0/dist/igv.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Local File Test</h1>

    <div id="igv-div" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px; border:1px solid lightgray"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var igvDiv = document.getElementById("igv-div");
        var options = {
            reference: {
                fastaURL: "test.fasta"
            }
        };

        igv.createBrowser(igvDiv, options)
            .then(function(browser) {
                console.log("Created IGV browser");
            })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

and here's the FASTA file

```
>HSBGPG Human gene for bone gla protein (BGP)
GGCAGATTCCCCCTAGACCCGCCCGCACCATGGTCAGGCATGCCCCTCCTCATCGCTGGGCACAGCCCAGAGGGT
ATAAACAGTGCTGGAGGCTGGCGGGGCAGGCCAGCTGAGTCCTGAGCAGCAGCCCAGCGCAGCCACCGAGACACC
ATGAGAGCCCTCACACTCCTCGCCCTATTGGCCCTGGCCGCACTTTGCATCGCTGGCCAGGCAGGTGAGTGCCCC
CACCTCCCCTCAGGCCGCATTGCAGTGGGGGCTGAGAGGAGGAAGCACCATGGCCCACCTCTTCTCACCCCTTTG
GCTGGCAGTCCCTTTGCAGTCTAACCACCTTGTTGCAGGCTCAATCCATTTGCCCCAGCTCTGCCCTTGCAGAGG
GAGAGGAGGGAAGAGCAAGCTGCCCGAGACGCAGGGGAAGGAGGATGAGGGCCCTGGGGATGAGCTGGGGTGAAC
CAGGCTCCCTTTCCTTTGCAGGTGCGAAGCCCAGCGGTGCAGAGTCCAGCAAAGGTGCAGGTATGAGGATGGACC
TGATGGGTTCCTGGACCCTCCCCTCTCACCCTGGTCCCTCAGTCTCATTCCCCCACTCCTGCCACCTCCTGTCTG
GCCATCAGGAAGGCCAGCCTGCTCCCCACCTGATCCTCCCAAACCCAGAGCCACCTGATGCCTGCCCCTCTGCTC
CACAGCCTTTGTGTCCAAGCAGGAGGGCAGCGAGGTAGTGAAGAGACCCAGGCGCTACCTGTATCAATGGCTGGG
GTGAGAGAAAAGGCAGAGCTGGGCCAAGGCCCTGCCTCTCCGGGATGGTCTGTGGGGGAGCTGCAGCAGGGAGTG
GCCTCTCTGGGTTGTGGTGGGGGTACAGGCAGCCTGCCCTGGTGGGCACCCTGGAGCCCCATGTGTAGGGAGAGG
AGGGATGGGCATTTTGCACGGGGGCTGATGCCACCACGTCGGGTGTCTCAGAGCCCCAGTCCCCTACCCGGATCC
CCTGGAGCCCAGGAGGGAGGTGTGTGAGCTCAATCCGGACTGTGACGAGTTGGCTGACCACATCGGCTTTCAGGA
GGCCTATCGGCGCTTCTACGGCCCGGTCTAGGGTGTCGCTCTGCTGGCCTGGCCGGCAACCCCAGTTCTGCTCCT
CTCCAGGCACCCTTCTTTCCTCTTCCCCTTGCCCTTGCCCTGACCTCCCAGCCCTATGGATGTGGGGTCCCCATC
ATCCCAGCTGCTCCCAAATAAACTCCAGAAG
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Have you reached to the IGV.js developers?  What is the "error" that you get

Comment: I have not reached out to the developers - I want sure where to do that.  The error says "cannot find chromosomename of undefined" or something similar.  The key being "undefined"which I interpret as, it did not load the specified file.

Comment: The exact error I get is a dialog box stating:  Cannot read property 'getHomeChromosomeName' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the script is looking for a URL (fastaURL) so you could try specifying the file as file://directory/test.fasta

By default though, javascript cannot read local files from disk for security reasons. Are you sure it is even possible to specify a local file in your script in this way?  If yes, then the problem is likely that you need to specify the path correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I tried specifying the file as you suggested, but no luck.  Perhaps it is the JavaScript limitation.  I suppose I respect why that design decision is made, but for in internal use only purpose, it seems limiting.

Comment: One way to get round it is to host the web page and the FASTA file together in your own local webserver directory.  OSX has a built in local webserver that you can switch on without too much difficulty - then open the page from your browser using http://localhost/test.html   You would then be able to refer to the FASTA file as test.fasta as your script does now (URL relative to the calling page).

Comment: That did the trick.  Both files must be on a server and it does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

just stumbled on this.  I'm the developer of igv.js.  Please feel free to open issues and questions on our git forum,  I don't often have time to browse other forums.

Browsers will not allow loading of local files by file path in javascript, if they did it would be a gigantic security hole.  This restriction includes "file://" urls.  Local files can be loaded by user action (clicking a button),  that is supported in igv.js but there is no button for it as igv.js is designed as a component to embed in pages, not an application by itself.  For an example see igv.org/app (https://github.com/igvteam/igv-webapp),  a minimal application wrapping igv.js.  You'll find "local file" options for genomes and tracks there.